# series of probabilities diverging

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Let $ A_1, ... $ independent events, suppose the series of general term $P(A_i)$ diverge, let $k \in \mathbb{N^*}$ then we note : $\forall n \geq k : $ $$ C_n = \bigcup_{k \leq i \leq n} A_i$$ verify that $\sum_{i=k}^\infty P(A_i) = \infty$
so there is my idea : $\sum_{i=k}^\infty P(A_i) =  \sum_{i=1}^\infty P(A_i) - \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} P(A_i) = \infty$ is this valid?

Comment: did you mean to write $\sum_{i=k}^\infty P(A_i) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty P(A_i) - \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} P(A_i)$?

Comment: $\sum\limits_{i=k}^{n} a_i =\infty$ if and only if $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} a_i =\infty$ (if $a_i$ is a real number for each $i$). What has this to do with probability theory?

Comment: yes @FZan is that correct ?

Comment: @geetha290krm i mean is what i wrote correct ?